# Whats the best way to pivot duplicates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, pivot, window-functions

I have the following table:

[image]

What is the best way in SQL Server to pivot this table so it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please avoid images and instead use formatted text as it makes it much easier for people to answer.

Comment: I do NOT see duplicates!

Comment: @MaciejLos the keys are duplicated.

Comment: Keys - yes, but the entire datarow  - no!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select key,
    max(case when rn = 1 then email end) email1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then email end) email2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then email end) email3
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by key order by email) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by key
```

You can add more conditional `max()`s to the `select` clause to handle more than 3 `email`s per `key`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest combining them into a *single* column rather than placing them in different columns:

```
select key, string_agg(email, ',') within group (order by email)
from t
group by key;
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering the values of `email` column for each `key` might differ(*can be 2 or 5, while 3 as in the current case*), the number of pivoted columns should change. In order to get dynamic column count, the following way might be preferred :

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),  @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = 
       STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT('email',[rn])) AS email
                FROM 
                (
                 SELECT t.*, 
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [key] ORDER BY [key]) AS rn
                   FROM t
                ) q
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

SET @query = 
   N'SELECT *  
       FROM
       (
        SELECT t.*, 
               CONCAT(''email'',ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [key] ORDER BY [key])) AS rn
          FROM t
       ) q
       PIVOT 
       (
         MAX([email]) FOR [rn] IN (' + @cols + N' )
       ) p '

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=92c177ea5107b28dec788285e043dc33)</kbd>